# Issue in converting Timespan variable to 12 hour format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a nullable variable `Start time`

```
Timespan? st=e.StartTime;//Null-able variable;
```

I am trying to get time in `AM/PM` format but I am unable to get it.

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(st.ToString());
String f = String.Format("{0:hh:mm:tt}", date);
```

Error is:

```
 System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to output the results of `st.ToString()`, you will find that it doesn't contain any date information, only hours, minutes and seconds.

This isn't a valid format for a DateTime, which generally contain date and time information.

You don't need to convert your TimeSpan to a DateTime to format it, you can just use `TimeSpan.ToString()`:

```
string f = st.Value.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:tt");
```

For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx

Also, note the `\` before the `:`, you must do this if you want to include literal strings in the output, as mentioned at the bottom of that documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a timespan to a date is not possible, a timespan represents x amount of minutes/hours/whatever and you cannot get an exact date from that alone. If you have a date as a starting point, you can add a timespan and that will give you the new date.

Answer (score 0):

`st.ToString()` will return `"System.Nullable<Timespan>"` because that is what a nullable type returns - it does not override the default Object.ToString implementation, so returns the type name.

If you want the string of the actual timespan, then you would need to do `st.Value.ToString()`, but you should be checking for null first (i.e. `st.HasValue == true`)

Edit: Also see [@Sean's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17341177/1908) comment about how to output the Timespan without converting to a DateTime first.

Edit: Turns out I was slightly wrong - st.ToString() doesn't return the above. So see Sean's answer.

Comment: get error as System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value when i use st.HasValue==true

Comment: You can always just check if the object is not null, then break into a block, like so:
`if (st != null) { string f = st.Value.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:tt"); }`

Comment: @Sean even when i use you solution i get System.FormatException Input string was not in a correct format

Answer (score 0):

First convert Timespan to Datetime by adding TimeSpan to a base date of 00:00 hrs. Then on that dateTime derive the 12 hr format.

```
DateTime.Now.Date.Add(OpenTimeSpan).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:tt")
```

Answer (score 0):

The Accepted Answer is wrong.
You cannot return AM/PM for a TimeSpan because it is *only* concerned with the *length* of Time,
     ***not*** a Time of Day - hench the name, "*TimeSpan*".
Convert to a DateTime first before converting to a String:

```
string sTimeOfDay = new DateTime().Add(st).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

**Note**: If your TimeSpan is nullable, then you will need to add Conditional Logic to Handle Nulls and pass in `ts.Value` instead of `ts`:

```
string sTimeOfDay = (st == null ? null : new DateTime().Add(st.value).ToString("hh:mm tt") );
```